# Which was the first anime to feature instant transmission?

Tags: tropes

Several anime characters have the ability to use instant transmission or teleportation by their own means. Some of them are, Goku in Dragon Ball Z, Merlin in Nanatsu no Taizai, Ryo Shimazaki in Mob Psycho 100, Shirai Kuroko in Toaru Kagaku no Railgun and Jibril in No Game No Life. But which was the first anime to feature a character who could do that?

Which was the first anime to feature instant tranmission?

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can see Dragon Ball Z was the first one to do so. Sailor Moon also showed teleportation but Dragon Ball Z was aired before Sailor Moon so it was the first anime to feature teleportation. I was checking the list of MCs in anime which could cast teleportation and found that Dragon Ball franchise was the oldest one in that list.
Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anime_and_manga_characters_who_can_teleport